# Appending network pc to sys.path

Tags: python, networking, import, directory, sys.path

Is it possible to add network pc to sys.path? Currently I'm only able to append a shared folder. When I try to import a script inside this folder I get ImportError. I have the **init** file in there. As I know this might be because sys.path doesn't actually see the appended folder itself but the files, folders inside?

Because import works from a folder inside the first folder.

directory structure:

*//PC023/SharedFolder/folder*

so i'm soing this:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.normpath("//PC023/SharedFolder"))
```

then I try to import:
`from SharedFolder import script` -> I get ImportError saying no module exists with this name.

if I do `from folder import script2` -> it works

My question is what is the real reason the import doesn't work and can I append the directory like this:

`sys.path.append(os.path.normpath("//PC023"))` - > because it doesn't seem to work this way